# React, Why selected checkboxes are not checked in case of new selection?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have list of items that I am showing in Checkboxlist. Items are coming from get webapi and it returns xml. Some of the items are checked on page load. If I make the change in the selection, always only new selection will stay. Why pre-fill selected checkboxes are no more selected in case of change in the selection.

```
Xml:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <Product>
    <states is-assigned="FALSE" product-state-id="11">Alabama</states>
    <states is-assigned="FALSE" product-state-id="12">Alaska</states>
    <states is-assigned="FALSE" product-state-id="21">Arizona</states>
    <states is-assigned="TRUE" product-state-id="22">Colorado</states> selected on page load
    <states is-assigned="TRUE" product-state-id="33">Connect</states> selected on page load
  </Product>
</xml>
```

```
import React from "react";
import axios from 'axios';
import XMLParser from 'react-xml-parser';

export class AssignStates extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      Template_ID: "",
      templatestates: [],
      checkedItems: [],
    }

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }
  
  handleChange(event) {
    const id = parseInt(event.target.id, 10);
    const index = this.state.checkedItems.indexOf(id);
    const updatedArray = [...this.state.checkedItems];
    if (index !== -1) {
      updatedArray.splice(index, 1);
    } else {
      updatedArray.push(id);
    }
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      checkedItems: updatedArray
    }));
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const StateID_List = this.state.checkedItems;
    const Template_ID = this.props.key_id;
    const data = {
      Template_ID,
      StateID_List
    }

    fetch(REQUEST_URL, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error))
      .then(response => console.log('Success', response));
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if (typeof this.props.key_id !== 'undefined') {
      const Template_ID = this.props.key_id;

      if (Template_ID > 0) {
        this.getListOfStates(Template_ID);
      }
    }
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    const Template_ID = this.props.key_id;

    if (prevProps.key_id !== this.props.key_id) {
      console.log(`key_id: ${this.props.key_id}`);
      this.getListOfStates(Template_ID);
    }
  }

  getListOfStates(Template_ID) {
    axios.get(REQUEST_URL, { "Content-Type": "application/xml; charset=utf-8" })
      .then(response => {
        const jsonDataFromXml = new XMLParser().parseFromString(response.data);

        console.log(jsonDataFromXml.getElementsByTagName('states'));
      })
      .then((data) => {
        let items = data.reduce((acc, item) => {
          if (item.attributes['is-assigned'] === "TRUE") acc.push(item.attributes['product-state-id']);

          return acc;
      }, [])

      this.setState({
        templatestates: data,
        checkedItems: items
      });

      console.log(items);
    })
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <ul style={{ listStyle: 'none' }}>
            {(this.state.templatestates.map((item, index) => {
              return (
                <li key={item.attributes['product-state-id']}>
                  <input
                    type="checkbox"
                    id={item.attributes['product-state-id']}
                    defaultChecked={item.attributes['is-assigned'] == "TRUE" ? true : false}
                    value={item.value}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                  />                                                                            
                  &nbsp; {item.value}
                </li>                                                             
              )                                                            
            }))}
          </ul>                                                                               
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>

          &nbsp;&nbsp;
          <input type="button" name="selectall" value="Select All" />

          &nbsp;&nbsp;
          <input type="button" name="unselectall" value="Clear All" />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default AssignStates;
```

Thanks

Comment: What exactly is the issue? Is the `defaultChecked` prop not setting as you expect? Are the checkboxes not toggling? Can you clarify the issue?

Comment: I've created a running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-why-selected-checkboxes-are-not-checked-in-case-of-new-selection-3x6e62) of your code and it seems the XML data is parsed and "Colorado" and "Connect" are checked. It's not clear what you are asking for help with. It's also a bit odd that you are rendering ***controlled*** inputs but specifying a `defaultChecked` prop. The "defaultX" props are generally used for ***uncontrolled*** inputs.

Comment: Thanks Drew. I am new to react. You can modify my code if you find it not appropriate. On page load, Colarado and Connect checkboxes are checked. Now I want to check Alabama and Alaska also with Colarado and Connect. After form submit, its only showing the new selection, but not showing the existing selection.

Answer (score 0):

in getListOfStates function i see you are updating the result in prodtemplatestates state. But there is no state named "prodtemplatestates"!!

Comment: I fixed it in the getlistofstates. Issue is still there.

Comment: I think i understand where is the problem. you are making the checkboxes fill with the condition of "{item.attributes['is-assigned'] == "TRUE" ? true : false}". But when you are clicking the checkbox it pushes that box id to "checkedItems". But you are not using that checkedItems anywhere in you html. make a conditon that will check both the is-assigned' and the checkedItems .

Comment: I agree with Asifur. I updated the getlistoftstates function. my code is not working. please look into my getlistofstates code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `checkedItems` state should be initialized to the selected XML values when the component mounts.

```
getListOfStates(Template_ID) {
  axios
    .get(REQUEST_URL, { "Content-Type": "application/xml; charset=utf-8" })
    .then((response) => {
      const jsonDataFromXml = new XMLParser().parseFromString(data);
      const states = jsonDataFromXml.getElementsByTagName("states");
      console.log(states);

      this.setState({
        templatestates: states,
        checkedItems: states
          .filter(({ attributes }) => attributes["is-assigned"] === "TRUE")
          .map(({ attributes }) => Number(attributes["product-state-id"]))
      });
    });
}
```

When mapping the checkbox inputs you should use the `checked` prop for a controlled input (*i.e. `checked` and `onChange` props*). Use `this.state.checkedItems` array and check if the current mapped `item`'s id is in the array.

```
<ul style={{ listStyle: "none" }}>
  {this.state.templatestates.map((item, index) => {
    return (
      <li key={item.attributes["product-state-id"]}>
        <label>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            id={item.attributes["product-state-id"]}
            checked={this.state.checkedItems.includes(
              Number(item.attributes["product-state-id"])
            )}
            value={item.value}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
          &nbsp; {item.value}
        </label>
      </li>
    );
  })}
</ul>
```

[image: Edit react-why-selected-checkboxes-are-not-checked-in-case-of-new-selection]

Comment: Thanks. Code works perfectly. How to do select all checkboxes and clear all checkboxes in the above code. I have two buttons Select All and Clear All?

Comment: Also, how to enable/disable checkboxes on page load ?

Comment: How to enable/disable checkboxes on page load?  If is-assigned=False, checkbox is disabled, if is-assigned=true, checkbox is enabled.                                      
 <states is-assigned="FALSE" product-state-id="11">Alabama</states>
    <states is-assigned="FALSE" product-state-id="12">Alaska</states>
    <states is-assigned="FALSE" product-state-id="21">Arizona</states>
    <states is-assigned="TRUE" product-state-id="22">Colorado</states> selected on page load .

Comment: @TestUser You can create a `toggleAll` function that either maps all of `this.state.templatestates` to an array of selected `product-state-id` values to the `this.state.checkedItems` array to mark them all checked, or sets the `this.state.checkedItems` array to an empty array to de-select them all. I've updated the codesandbox with this function and enabled the buttons.

Comment: @TestUser AFAIK the XML items with `is-assigned="TRUE"` *are* selected when they load. Is this not the case? Or are you referring to something else?

Comment: Thanks Drew. In some of the components, I need to show the checkboxes as selected when is-assigned="TRUE". In few components, I need to enable the checkbox rows when is-assigned="TRUE" and disable other rows for is-assigned="FALSE".

Comment: @TestUser This all sounds a bit extracurricular to the question here of initializing the checkboxes from the XML and toggling them for the submit handler. If it's related to your question here can you update your post to include all relevant code and details? If it's extra "stuff" it would be better to create a new post with a new question/issue. If you create a new post feel free to ping me here with a link to it and I can check it out.

Comment: Hi Drew,. It's the same functionality that I need to display list of checkboxes. Now I need to enable and disable the checkbox rows depending upon is-assigned="TRUE" or "FALSE". If the checkboxes are enabled, in that case only the user can select the checkbox . thanks

Comment: toggle functionality is working great. Thanks a lot for all the help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247001/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-testuser).

Comment: Drew, I created a post. Please look into it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73257022/react-enable-disable-checkboxlist-data-depending-upon-data-attribute-on-page-lo

Comment: Hi Drew, please find my new post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73612264/react-how-to-replace-unordered-list-bullets-with-images-in-the-treeview