# React, enable/disable checkboxlist data depending upon data attribute on page load?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have list of items that I am showing in Checkboxlist. Items are coming from get webapi and it returns xml. On Page load, in case of is-assigned="FALSE" checkboxes are disabled, and in case of is-assigned="TRUE", checkboxes are enabled. User can only select checkboxes that are enabled.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <Product>
<states is-assigned="FALSE" product-state-id="11">Alabama</states> disable
<states is-assigned="FALSE" product-state-id="12">Alaska</states>disable
<states is-assigned="FALSE" product-state-id="21">Arizona</states>
<states is-assigned="TRUE" product-state-id="22">Colorado</states> enable on page load
<states is-assigned="TRUE" product-state-id="33">Connect</states> enable on page load
  </Product>
</xml>

export class AssignStates extends React.Component {
       constructor(props) {
       super(props);
             this.state = {
                    Template_ID: "",
                    templatestates: [],
                    checkedItems: [],
             }
             this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
       }
       handleChange(event) {
             const id = Number(event.target.id);
             const index = this.state.checkedItems.indexOf(id);
             const updatedArray = [...this.state.checkedItems];
             if (index !== -1) {
                    updatedArray.splice(index, 1);
             } else {
                    updatedArray.push(id);
             }
             this.setState((prevState) => ({
                    checkedItems: updatedArray
             }));
       }
       componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
             const Template_ID = this.props.key_id;
             if (prevProps.key_id !== this.props.key_id) {
                    console.log(`key_id: ${this.props.key_id}`);
                    this.getListOfStates(Template_ID);
             }
       }
       getListOfStates(Template_ID) {
             axios
     .get(REQUEST_URL, { "Content-Type": "application/xml; charset=utf-8" })
      .then((response) => {
 const jsonDataFromXml = new XMLParser().parseFromString(response.data);
 const states = jsonDataFromXml.getElementsByTagName("states");
 console.log(states);
 this.setState({
  templatestates: states,
  checkedItems: states
 .filter(({ attributes }) => attributes["is-assigned"] === "TRUE")
 .map(({ attributes }) => Number(attributes["product-state-id"]))
});
});
}
render() {
return (
<div>
<form>
<div>
<ul>                                                                                                     {this.state.templatestates.map((item, index) => {                                                                                                          return (                                                                                                                 <li key={item.attributes["product-state-id"]}>                                                                                                               <label>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    <input type="checkbox" id={item.attributes["product-state-id"]}                                                                                                                                     checked={this.state.checkedItems.includes(                                                                                                                                          Number(item.attributes["product-state-id"])                                                                                                                                   )}                                                                                                                                   value={item.value}                                                                                                                                   onChange={this.handleChange}                                                                                                                             />
          &nbsp; {item.value}                                                                                                                   </label>                                                                                                              </li>                                                                                                          );                                                                                                    })}                                                                                            </ul>
                                                                     </div>
                                                                                                                     <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
     </div>
             );
       }
}

export default AssignStates;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When computing the `states` value that is returned for the `this.state.templatestates` state value map the `states` array and inject a `disabled` property into each item. When mapping `this.state.templatestates` to the checkbox inputs set the `disabled` prop accordingly.

Example:

```
getListOfStates(Template_ID) {
  axios
    .get(REQUEST_URL, { "Content-Type": "application/xml; charset=utf-8" })
    .then((response) => {
      const jsonDataFromXml = new XMLParser().parseFromString(response.data);
      console.log(jsonDataFromXml.getElementsByTagName('states'));

      const states = jsonDataFromXml.getElementsByTagName("states");

      this.setState({
        templatestates: states.map((el) => ({
          ...el,
          disabled: el.attributes["is-assigned"] === "FALSE" // <-- inject disabled property
        })),
        checkedItems: states
          .filter(({ attributes }) => attributes["is-assigned"] === "TRUE")
          .map(({ attributes }) => Number(attributes["product-state-id"]))
      });
    });
}
```

...

```
{this.state.templatestates.map((item, index) => {
  return (
    <li key={item.attributes["product-state-id"]}>
      <label>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          id={item.attributes["product-state-id"]}
          checked={this.state.checkedItems.includes(
            Number(item.attributes["product-state-id"])
          )}
          value={item.value}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          disabled={item.disabled} // <-- set disabled prop on input
        />
        &nbsp; {item.value}
      </label>
    </li>
  );
})}
```

To "toggle all" only the assigned items then filter the `templatestates` array prior to mapping the id values.

```
toggleAll = (checked) => () =>
  this.setState((prevState) => ({
    checkedItems: checked
      ? prevState.templatestates
          .filter(({ attributes }) => attributes["is-assigned"] === "TRUE")
          .map(({ attributes }) => Number(attributes["product-state-id"]))
      : []
  }));
```

[image: Edit react-enable-disable-checkboxlist-data-depending-upon-data-attribute-on-page-lo]

Comment: Thanks Drew. Enable/Disable works perfectly. Highly appreciate for all the help. Please let me know how to score the answers.                                                                            Also, I have another question in another post. Not sure on page load, state and props is returning null.  Please help me . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73261257/react-why-state-or-props-null-on-page-refresh

Comment: Hi Drew, what needs to be done so that SelectAll button can only checked the enabled checkboxes only.

Comment: Hi Drew, the question is related to the original post. please find code in the sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-why-selected-checkboxes-are-not-checked-in-case-of-new-selection-forked-86ki1s?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js&theme=dark.   I just found that SelectAll button checks the disabled checkboxes also. what needs to be done so that Select all only check enabled checkboxes only.

Comment: @TestUser Filter the array prior to mapping the checked id values, similar to how they were initially selected. I've updated the answer and linked codesandbox.

Comment: I have another post. Please find my new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74512897/react-session-timeout-no-button-expires-the-session-immediately. No button click: how to close the dialog and session will expire in 2 minutes and redirect to the session expired page. how this can be achieved? thanks a lot.

Comment: @TestUser It seems that question is a duplicate, and the original question you posted as an answer already that seems logical. Is that answer not sufficient?

Comment: Not able to able to understand what needs to be fixed.