# React: why state or props null on page refresh?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am displaying a tree view on left frame of the page. Tree is generating from xml file. On the click of each node, components are opening in the right frame of the page. ProductsTreeView is the tree component, Add_Category is the component that will open on the click of one of the tree node. I am passing the props through routing. everything is working fine as long as the page not refresh. In case of page refresh, props is showing null in the Add_Category page. Please help how to fix this.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeYB6.gif

```
App.js

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Switch, Route, BrowserRouter, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from './components/Home';

 export class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <BrowserRouter>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route path="/" component={Home} />
                        <Redirect to="/" />
                    </Switch>
                </BrowserRouter>
             </div>
        );
    }
}
export default App;
_____________
 
Home.js

import React from 'react';
import { Route} from "react-router-dom";
import ProductsTree from '.ProductsTreeView';
import AddCategory from './Add_Category';

class Home extends React.Component 
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state =
        {
            currentNode: {},
            data: "",
        };
        this.setCurrentNode = this.setCurrentNode.bind(this);
    }

    setCurrentNode(node) {
        this.setState({ currentNode: node });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
<table className="Container">

<tbody><tr width="100%">

<td className="TreeContainer">

   <ProductsTree setCurrentNode={this.setCurrentNode} /> </td>

<td className="BodyContainer">

                                             <Route path="/Add_Category">

                                                    <AddCategory key_id={this.state.currentNode.key_id} />

                                                </Route>

                            </td>   </tr>        </tbody>    </table>

            </div>

        );

    }

}

export default Home;
_________________________

***Add_Category***
 
import React from 'react'

export class Add_Category extends React.Component {

       constructor(props) {

             super(props);

             this.state = {

                    ID: "",

                    Name: "",

             };

       }

       componentDidMount() {
         if (typeof this.props.key_id !== 'undefined') {
             const ID= this.props.key_id;
             this.getName(ID);
          }
       }

       componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {

             if (prevProps.key_id !== this.props.key_id) {

                    console.log(`key_id: ${this.props.key_id}`);
                    const ID= this.props.key_id;
                    this.getName(ID);

             }

       }
       async getName(ID) {
                   await fetch(REQUEST_URL)
                           .then(response => response.json())
                           .then((data) => {
                                 this.setState({
                                       Name: data,
                                      ID: this.props.key_id,
                                        loading: false})
                                 console.log(this.state.Name)
                           })[![enter image description here][1]][1]             
       }
      render() {
        return (
                    <div>
                          <form>
       {this.state.Name}

                                </form>

                           </div>

 

        );

    }

}

export default Add_Category;

_________________________
ProductsTreeView.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import ReactHtmlParser from 'react-html-parser';

import axios from 'axios';

import XMLParser from 'react-xml-parser';

import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

 

class ProductsTreeView extends Component {

    render() {

        return (

            <div id="TreeView">

                <TreeView setCurrentNode={this.props.setCurrentNode} />

            </div>

        );

    }

}

 

class Node {

    description = 'n/a';

    id = -1;

    key_id = -1;

    linkpagename = '';

    isActive = false;

    nodes = [];

 

    constructor(description, id, key_id, linkpagename) {

        this.description = description;

        this.id = id;

        this.key_id = key_id;

        this.linkpagename = linkpagename;

    }

 

    static nodesFromXml(xml) {

        const map = (entity, nodes) => {

            const id = entity.attributes['id'];

            const key_id = entity.attributes['key-id'];

            const descriptionText =

                entity.children[

                    entity.children.findIndex((child) => child.name === 'description')

                ].value;

            const entities = entity.children.filter(

                (child) => child.name === 'entity'

            );

            var linkPageName = entity.attributes['link-page-name'];

            linkPageName = linkPageName.replace(".aspx", "");

            const node = new Node(descriptionText, id, key_id, linkPageName);

            nodes.push(node);

            entities.forEach((entity) => map(entity, node.nodes));

        };

 

        const parsedData = new XMLParser().parseFromString(xml);

 

        const entities = parsedData.children.filter(

            (child) => child.name === 'entity'

        );

 

        const nodes = [];

        entities.forEach((entity) => map(entity, nodes));

        return nodes;

    }

}

 

class TreeView extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {

        super(props);

        this.state = { nodes: [] };

        this.toggleNode = this.toggleNode.bind(this);

    }

 

    componentDidMount() {

        axios

            .get(REQUEST_URL, { 'Content-Type': 'application/xml; charset=utf-8' })

            .then((response) =>

                this.setState({ nodes: Node.nodesFromXml(response.data) }))

                    .catch(function (error) {

                        if (error.response) {

                            // Request made and server responded

                            console.log(error.response.data);

                            console.log(error.response.status);

                            console.log(error.response.headers);

                        } else if (error.request) {

                            // The request was made but no response was received

                            console.log(error.request);

                        } else {

                            // Something happened in setting up the request that triggered an Error

                            console.log('Error', error.message);

                        }

 

                    });

    }

 

    render() {

        const nodes = this.state.nodes;

 

        return (

            <ul>

                 {nodes.map((node) => (

                    <TreeNode

                        id={node.id}

                        key={node.key_id}

                        node={node}

                        onToggle={this.toggleNode}

                        setCurrentNode={this.props.setCurrentNode}

                    />

                ))}

            </ul>

        );

    }

 

    toggleNode(node) {

        this.props.setCurrentNode(node);

 

        function _toggleNode(currentNode, node) {

            if (currentNode.id === node.id) { //currentNode.id === node.id)

                {

                    if (currentNode.key_id === node.key_id)

                    {

                        currentNode.isActive = !currentNode.isActive;

                    }

                }

            }

            else

            {

                currentNode.nodes.forEach((childNode) => _toggleNode(childNode, node));

            }

        }

 

        const nodes = this.state.nodes;

        nodes.forEach((currentNode) => _toggleNode(currentNode, node));

        this.setState((state) => (state.nodes = nodes));

    }

}

 

class TreeNode extends React.Component {

    render() {

        const node = this.props.node;

        const onToggle = this.props.onToggle;

        let activeChildren = null;

        if (node.isActive && node.nodes.length > 0) {

            activeChildren = (

                <ul>

                    {node.nodes.map((node) => (

                        <TreeNode

                            id={node.id}

                            key={node.key_id}

                            node={node}

                            onToggle={onToggle}

                        />

                    ))}

                </ul>

            );

        }

 

        return (

                <li

                id={node.id} linkpagename={node.linkpagename}

                key={node.key_id}

                onClick={(event) => {

                    event.stopPropagation();

                    onToggle(node);                 

                }}

            >

                <Link to={node.linkpagename} style={{ textDecoration: 'none', color: '#000000' }} >

{node.description}</Link>

             {activeChildren}

                </li>

           

        );

    }

}

export default ProductsTreeView;
```

thanks

Comment: Home component is showing tree control on the left part of the page. each node click opens a different component on the right part of the page. I am using routing. I am sending node id to the components that are showing in the right side. Everything is working fine as long as I am not refreshing the page. on Page refresh, state and props is empty in the AddCategory component. Its not showing any data on the AddCategory page after page refresh. Please help. I really need help regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

React state is ephemeral, it lives in memory. When the page is reloaded the app is reloaded. Anything in state is reset.

This appears to be a case of needing to persist the React state to longer-term storage so when the page is reloaded the state can be reinitialized.

Here's an example:

```
const initialState = {
  currentNode: {},
  data: "",
};

class Home extends React.Component 
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = initialState;
    this.setCurrentNode = this.setCurrentNode.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // initialize from storage
    this.setState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("homeState")) ?? initialState);
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    // persist updates to storage
    localStorage.setItem("homeState", JSON.stringify(this.state));
  }

  setCurrentNode(node) {
    this.setState({ currentNode: node });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <table className="Container">
          <tbody>
            <tr width="100%">
              <td className="TreeContainer">
                <ProductsTree setCurrentNode={this.setCurrentNode} />
              </td>
              <td className="BodyContainer">
                <Route path="/Add_Category">
                  <AddCategory key_id={this.state.currentNode.key_id} />
                </Route>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

If other components have state that needs to persist through page reloads they will also need to do this.

AddCategory

```
const initialState = {
  ID: "",
  Name: "",
}

const getStorageKey = (id) => `addCategory-${id}`;

export class AddCategory extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = initialState;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { key_id } = this.props;

    // initialize from storage
    this.setState(
      JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(getStorageKey(key_id))) ?? initialState
    );

    if (typeof key_id !== 'undefined') {
      this.getName(key_id);
    }
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    const { ID } = this.state;
    const { key_id } = this.props;

    if (prevProps.key_id !== key_id) {
      console.log(`key_id: ${key_id}`);
      this.getName(key_id);
    }

    if (prevState.ID !== ID) {
      // persist updates to storage
      localStorage.setItem(getStorageKey(ID), JSON.stringify(this.state));
    }
  }

  async getName(ID) {
    const response await fetch(REQUEST_URL);
    const data = await response.json();
    this.setState({
      Name: data,
      ID,
      loading: false
    });
  }

  render() {
    ...
  }
}
```

TreeView

```
class TreeView extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { nodes: [] };

    this.toggleNode = this.toggleNode.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // initialize from storage
    const storedState = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("treeview"));

    if (storedState) {
      this.setState(storedState);
    } else {
      axios.get(REQUEST_URL, { 'Content-Type': 'application/xml; charset=utf-8' })
        .then((response) => {
          this.setState(
            { nodes: Node.nodesFromXml(response.data) },
           () => {
              // persist updated state to storage
              localStorage.setItem("treeview", JSON.stringify(this.state));
            }
          );
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          ...
        });
    }
  }

  ...
}
```

Comment: It works on the right side of the page. on page refresh, it's retaining the data. Currently tree goes back to the initial state on page refresh. how to keep the state of the tree node or what level was opened at that time before page refresh.

Comment: @TestUser See the last comment of my answer. You'll need to do this for every component that cares about persisting its state through a page reload. An alternative, usually, is to implement global app state, i.e. redux, and then you only need to persist the entire state object from one location. Depends on your app's complexity though.

Comment: Hi Drew, I am not able to use redux as I need to rewrite everything. Redux is not in scope. I add a image showing how tree looks like. On click of each node, it opens a component showing the data depening on tree node id. I am passing the id to different components through routing. Please help how do modify TreeView and Add_category component provided with the question. Once, I know how to fix in those, I will fix in the remaining components. Thanks a lot for all the help.

Comment: @TestUser The concept of initializing from and persisting to localStorage is the same for each component, only the state value is different. I was only suggesting using a global app state so you'd only need to initialize/persist one object in one location. Is the issue you have with the `TreeView` and `Add_Category` components something to do with them making asynchronous API requests when they mount?

Comment: Hi Drew, I am not able to understand how to do this. From Home component, I am routing to Add_Category passing key_id. Its a node id I am passing. Please show me what change needs to be done in TreeView component and Add_Category components. In react, without using redux I cannot use the global state. Please set the state value in the local storage for TreeView and Add_Category components. Highly appreciate for the help.

Comment: @TestUser Ok, added code examples for those two components.

Comment: Hi Drew, I tried the solution in TreeView and AddCategory. Its still mot working. after page refresh, its not retaining the data, on tree node selection

Comment: @TestUser Would it be possible to create a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of your code that reproduces the issue that we could inspect and debug live?

Comment: Sure Drew. I will do that.