# React, How to replace Unordered list bullets with images in the TreeView?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using react. I am able to generate a tree from xml file. Currently treeview is showing as an unordered list. How to replace that with images?
Please find my sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/falling-waterfall-2irybs
The code is working fine in Visual Studio. I am not sure how to use sandbox, not able to understand sandbox error.
Images are also included in the Sandbox.

- On page load tree is collapsed showing service and sales two nodes with PLUS image.
- when node is open, image will convert into minus image. After expand, all opened nodes will show minus image except the last one. Last node will show paper image.

Please help in fixing my treeview code.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: it's better to post code inside the post, also if the code works but not in sandbox then the question isn't about a problem in code but a question about codesandbox itself

Answer (score 0):

You would need to re-style the `li` element's `::marker` selector. If you are open to using a 3rd-party css-in-JS solution then I would suggest using the [`styled-components`](https://styled-components.com/) package.

Here's an example implementation:

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import plus from "./plus.gif";
import minus from "./minus.gif";
import paper from "./paper.gif";

const StyledLI = styled.li`
  ::marker {
    content: url(${({ expanded, isLeaf }) =>
      isLeaf ? paper : expanded ? minus : plus});
  }
`;
```

Pass `expanded` and `isLeaf` props to the new styled component when rendering.

```
class TreeNode extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { node, onToggle } = this.props;

    const activeChildren =
      node.isActive && node.nodes.length ? (
        <ul>
          {node.nodes.map((node) => (
            <TreeNode
              id={node.id}
              key={node.key_id}
              node={node}
              onToggle={onToggle}
            />
          ))}
        </ul>
      ) : null;

    return (
      <StyledLI
        id={node.id}
        expanded={node.isActive}    // <-- expanded if active
        isLeaf={!node.nodes.length} // <-- leaf node if no children nodes
        linkpagename={node.linkpagename}
        key={node.key_id}
        onClick={(event) => {
          event.stopPropagation();
          onToggle(node);
        }}
      >
        <Link
          to={node.linkpagename}
          style={{ textDecoration: "none", color: "#000000" }}
        >
          {node.description}
        </Link>{" "}
        - {node.key_id} - {node.linkpagename}
        {activeChildren}
      </StyledLI>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Edit react-how-to-replace-unordered-list-bullets-with-images-in-the-treeview]

[image]

Comment: Thanks Drew. It works perfectly. Is there any way to display the images without third party component. Also, how to collapse all the open child nodes, if parent node is collapsing.Ex in the above image: If Service node is clicked once its expanded, all the nodes under it should be collapses also. Service node is collapsed with all the nodes under it.

Comment: @TestUser Yes, I believe you can move the images to the public directory and use CSS classes to apply a specific class to use specific image. It seems the `Node`s retain their `isActive` properties, so if you want to deactivate each node when a parent is deactivated you'll need to iterate the subtree and toggle all nodes back to `isActive = false`.

Comment: Hi Drew, not sure what needs to be updated in the code, so that if parent node is collapsed all the open child nodes will be closed too. please help.

Comment: @TestUser Your question was *specifically* about updating the unordered list bullet elements. Asking about this other behavior is a bit off-topic. I can take a look into this but it would be preferable to create a new post specific to this new question.